# Convert dict attributes in multiple attributes in Python

Tags: python, oop, dictionary

I have a class with a dict attribute, like this :

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.mydict = {'var1': 'value1', 'var2': 'value2', ...}
```

When I want to get the values, I have to do this :

```
cls = MyClass()
print(cls.mydict['var1'])
print(cls.mydict['var2'])
```

What is the solution to get the values directly in attributes please :

```
cls = MyClass()
print(cls.var1)
print(cls.var2)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add an additional function to the class that will be able to parse the dict and insert the relevant attributes:

```
def assign_variables( self ):
  for key, val in self.mydict.items():
    setattr( self, key, val )
```

I'm using the built-in [`setattr()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr) here to set attributes with dynamic names/values:

> This is the counterpart of `getattr()`. The arguments are an object, a string and an arbitrary value. The string may name an existing attribute or a new attribute. The function assigns the value to the attribute, provided the object allows it.
>   **For example, `setattr(x, 'foobar', 123)` is equivalent to `x.foobar = 123`**.

You can call this function inside your constructor after the `mydict` variable is defined or even just place the loop in the constructor.

Comment: In this case you now have two object references for each member of `mydict` stored in the class object instance. Seems like it would be better to only have one. This method could be changed in a very minor way to avoid this (just avoid `self.mydict` altogether by passing `mydict` to `assign_variables`).

Comment: @RickTeachey - correct. One would then have to ask why the dict needs to exist as an attribute if it's pre-defined and not simply assign the class attributes as-is without this conversion code. But then we'd be getting into the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: I was assuming it is pre-defined as a simplification of the problem presentation. Can't think of a reason you'd actually want to do it this way in practice.

Answer (score 4):

Using [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr), you can set attribute dynamically:

```
>>> class MyClass:
...     def __init__(self):
...         mydict = {'var1': 'value1', 'var2': 'value2'}
...         for key, value in mydict.items():
...             setattr(self, key, value)
...
>>> instance = MyClass()
>>> instance.var1
'value1'
>>> instance.var2
'value2'
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to implement `__getattr__`:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.mydict = {'var1': 'value1', 'var2': 'value2', ...}

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        try:
            return self.mydict[name]
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError("object %s has no attribute '%s'" % (self, name))
```

Comment: Raising a new error within the `except` statement like this seems to mess up the traceback - there are two traces, which is pretty confusing. Isn't there a better way?

Comment: @RickTeachey: not sure what python shell or python implementation you're using, but this code works as it should on all CPython versions I can remember (which means since 1.5.something).

Comment: It works fine, but it produces the message `During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:`. Might be my inexperience, but it doesn't seem very clean, and just doesn't seem like a very good way of doing things. `if name in self.mydict: return self.mydict[name]`, `else: raise AttributeError()` seems better. Or even: `try:` (etc etc), `except KeyError: pass`, `raise AttributeError()`.

Comment: Must be either a Python 3.x thing or your shell. And catching an exception to raise another one (from the except clause) is a very common idiom.

Comment: I am using 3.x in Anaconda (just plain Windows CMD).

Comment: Aha! PEP 415 describes the proper way to do this in Python 3.3, avoiding the messy traceback issues I described above. The last line should read `raise AttributeError("object %s has no attribute '%s'" % (self, name)) from None`

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `__repr__` method in your class to get required output.

Answer (score -1):

You can directly update the `__dict__` attribute of your object I believe:

```
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self):
        self.mydict = {'var1': 'value1', 'var2': 'value2', ...}
        self.__dict__.update(self.mydict)
```

Comment: *Warning*: this solution totally bypasses `__setattr__()` and all descriptors (properties or else) and can break quit-e a few things.

Comment: Is it not the case that object's `"__setattr__()"` basically assigns directly to `__dict__` anyway? (Genuine question, not being contrary). In this example the OP isn't inheriting anything so would this be any less safe than using `__setattr__()`?

Comment: `object.__setattr__()` takes care of descriptors and slots - assigning to `__dict__` is only done if there's no binding descriptor by the same name AND if the class uses a `__dict__` (=> doesn't use slots). Also you can have a customised `__setattr__` somewhere in the class hierarchy.  So yes, in this case (well, for what we can see of the code, that is)  you can say it's "safe" - until someone tries to add descriptors etc... To make a long story short: only use this solution if your class is of the brainless data-bag kind (iow a dict with dotted syntax).

Comment: As others have noted: tons of pitfalls for this method, and there's really no reason to use it when you can just as easily use `for k, v in self.mydict.items(): self.__setattr__(k,v)`.

Answer (score -1):

Another way would be to override `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` together, which avoids having two object references to the same attribute in the class instance object (one O.R. to `value1` inside `myobj.mydict['var1']`, and another O.R. to `value1` in `myobj.__dict__['var1']`):

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__['_mydict'] = {'var1': 'value1', 'var2': 'value2'}
    #Note: using the @property (descriptor) is optional. I think it makes 
    #things more convenient.
    @property
    def mydict(self):
        return self._mydict
    #NOTE: __getattr__ won't get called if att is found in self.__dict__ first! 
    def __getattr__(self,att):
        if att in self.mydict:       # or without using @property: if att in self._mydict:
            return self.mydict[att]  #                                  return self._mydict[att]
        else:
            raise AttributeError("'{n}' object has no attribute '{a}'".format(n = type(self).__name__, a = att))
    def __setattr__(self,att,val):
        super().__setattr__(att, val)
        if att in self.mydict:
            self.mydict[att] = val   # or without using @property: self._mydict[att] = val
            self.__delattr__(att)    # remove duplicate copy of object reference to att
```

Note that doing it this way means you cannot add more key,value pairs to `mydict` unless you call the property directly, e.g.:

```
myobj = MyClass()
myobj.x = 1
myobj.mydict #note that result does not contain an entry for 'x'
myobj.mydict['x'] = 2
myobj.mydict #now it does
```

Also note that *getting* and *deleting* the `mydict` members will be overridden by any existing attribute of the same name (not only that, but you can't delete `mydict` members *at all* unless you **also** override `__delattr__` to enable this behavior):

```
#continuing the above code session
assert myobj.x == 1 #myobj.x is coming from self.x, not from self._mydict['x']
myobj.var1 = 'a new value'
myobj.var1 #results in 'a new value' as expected, but where is it coming from? 
assert myobj.mydict['var1'] == 'a new value' #Ah: it's coming from self._mydict as expected
assert myobj.__dict__['var1'] #ERROR, as expected
del myobj.x
assert myobj.x == 2 #now myobj.x is coming from self._mydict['x'], self.x having been deleted
del myobj.var1 #raises AttributeError; attributes in mydict can't be deleted (unless you also override __delattr__
```

If you want to change this behavior, you have to override `__getattribute__` (EDIT: which, as  bruno desthuilliers notes below, is usually not a good idea).

Comment: Your implementation of `__setattr__` does not respect the descriptor protocol. As a general rule, overridding `__setattr__` and `__getattribute__` is seldom a good idea - it can be tricky and can lead to poor performances.

Comment: First of all: I *didn't* override `__getattribute__`, but `__getattr__`. I only said you'd have to do that in order to look inside `mydict` first. If that's the primary reason for the downvote, I submit it's unwarranted. Second: How does it not respect the descriptor protocol? The get method is called using `[]`, and something is done with its return. That's what descriptors are for, is it not? If I'm wrong please point me somewhere so I can learn about what you mean. In any case, the descriptor is incidental, making things more convenient; it's still a useful solution to the OP's problem.

Comment: In light of my inexperience, and trust in your judgment as an obviously much more experienced person, I have edited my answer to make it clear the descriptor is optional.

Comment: I'm not talking about `__getattr__` - which is optional and only invoked (if defined) as a last resort, but about `__setattr__` which (together with `__getattribute__`) implement the attribute resolution rules. And I think you don't really get the point about descriptors - it's not about adding a `mydict` property, it's about looking the class and mro for binding descriptors (descriptors that implement `__set__`) and invoking them _before_ falling back to instance storage.

Comment: I know it's just a comment so it just isn't the space for a lengthy explanation, but I still don't understand the specific problem that is being caused by using a `dict` descriptor in the manner above. As for `__setattr__`, you have a point and I remember now the correct way to do this. Have edited accordingly.

Comment: once again it has *nothing* to do with your `mydict` property, it's about your implementation of `__setattr__` that doesn't do it's job correctly, ie *first* looking for binding descriptors in the class and it's mro, and invoking them if found. Your "corrected" implementation is better but it's still broken -  descriptors must be looked up *before* instance storage.

Comment: i think i understand what you're saying. not sure if the latest edit is an improvement or not. what do you think?

Comment: I thinks this is a good example of why overridding `__setattr__` is usually not a good idea - unless you have a really compelling reason to so, that is, and then you'd better do it right (which is still not the case in your last edit - if you have a binding descriptor by the same name as a key in `mydict`, you *DONT* want to update `mydict` nor `del` this attribute).

Comment: This has been a helpful conversation. I'd love to see an example of a correctly overridden `__setattr__` that doesn't violate/cause these sorts of considerations/problems. Surely it is possible.

Comment: Well yes it is of course possible - but it can be tricky... The C source code (object.c and typeobject.c) might be a good start.

Comment: I'll do that. It would be pretty great if you did a self-answered question on this topic since you seem to have a lot to say about it. As a part of that I'd also be interested in sample code showing how my implementation above is broken. Thanks for the back and forth.