# What tests can I perform to ensure I have overridden __setattr__ correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, setattr

I have been studying Python for a little while now, and I've come to understand that overriding `__setattr__` correctly can be troublesome ([to say the least](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27361072/2437514)!).

What are some effective ways to ensure/prove to myself the override has been done correctly? I'm specifically concerned about ensuring the override remains consistent with the descriptor protocol and MRO.

(Tagged as Python 3.x since that's what I am using, but the question is certainly applicable to other versions as well.)

Example code in which the "override" exhibits default behavior (but how can I prove it?):

```
class MyClass():
    def __setattr__(self,att,val):
        print("I am exhibiting default behavior!")
        super().__setattr__(att,val)
```

Contrived example in which the override violates the descriptor protocol (instance storage lookup occurs prior to the descriptor lookup - but how can I test it?):

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self,mydict):
        self.__dict__['mydict'] = mydict
    @property
    def mydict(self):
        return self._mydict
    def __setattr__(self,att,val):
        if att in self.mydict:
            self.mydict[att] = val
        else:
            super().__setattr__(att, val)
```

The ideal answer will provide a general test that will succeed when `__setattr__` has been overridden correctly, and fail otherwise.

Comment: What are you currently testing?

Comment: Nothing in particular. This is a general question. I was considering how to do this and couldn't think of any way to do it (such as getting a log or print statement to execute for each step of the attribute setting order so as to reveal what order they were completed- not sure how to do that). But I'm also very inexperienced.

Comment: @RickTeachey: sorry, I misread. The problem was that the original overridden `__setattr__` version was't being called. Since `object.__setattr__` was never invoked, descriptors with a setter would never be invoked either.

Comment: The answers are both great solutions and it was hard to choose between them. In the end I went with Bruno's just because it was more specific to addressing this particular problem.

Answer (score 3):

In this case there's a simple solution: add a binding descriptor with a name that's in `mydict` and test that assigning to that name goes thru the descriptor (NB : Python 2.x code, I don't have a Python 3 install here):

```
class MyBindingDescriptor(object):
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key

    def __get__(self, obj, cls=None):
        if not obj:
            return self
        return obj.__dict__[self.key]

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        obj.__dict__[self.key] = value


sentinel = object()

class MyClass(object):
    test = MyBindingDescriptor("test")

    def __init__(self, mydict):
        self.__dict__['mydict'] = mydict
        self.__dict__["test"] = sentinel

    def __setattr__(self, att, val):
        if att in self.mydict:
            self.mydict[att] = val
        else:
            super(MyClass, self).__setattr__(att, val)


# first test our binding descriptor
instance1 = MyClass({})
# sanity check 
assert instance1.test is sentinel, "instance1.test should be sentinel, got '%s' instead" % instance1.test

# this one should pass ok
instance1.test = NotImplemented
assert instance1.test is NotImplemented, "instance1.test should be NotImplemented, got '%s' instead" % instance1.test

# now demonstrate that the current implementation is broken:
instance2 = MyClass({"test":42})
instance2.test = NotImplemented
assert instance2.test is NotImplemented, "instance2.test should be NotImplemented, got '%s' instead" % instance2.test
```

Comment: I've searched and can't find much about binding descriptors. Is "binding descriptor" equivalent to "data descriptor"? If not, are there "non binding" descriptors? Also: I understand the test above and it's a pretty clever way of demonstrating that mro has been violated. Is there a general way to prove that the mro has NOT been violated for any given implementation?

Comment: Yes, "binding descriptor" means the same as "data descriptor": a descriptor that implements `__set__()`.  wrt/ the above test, it has few to do with mro ("method resolution order" aka looking up the inheritance tree) since there's no inheritance involved, it's about respecting binding descriptors.

Comment: Ok. I'm getting my terminology mixed up then.

Answer (score 2):

If you define overriding `__setattr__` correctly as *calling the `__setattr__` of the parent class* then you could graft your method into a class hierarchy that defines its own custom `__setattr__`:

```
def inject_tester_class(cls):
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        self._TesterClass__setattr_args.append((name, value))
        super(intermediate, self).__setattr__(name, value)
    def assertSetAttrDelegatedFor(self, name, value):
        assert \
            [args for args in self._TesterClass__setattr_args if args == (name, value)], \
            '__setattr__(name, value) was never delegated'
    body = {
        '__setattr__': __setattr__,
        'assertSetAttrDelegatedFor': assertSetAttrDelegatedFor,
        '_TesterClass__setattr_args': []
    }

    intermediate = type('TesterClass', cls.__bases__, body)
    testclass = type(cls.__name__, (intermediate,), vars(cls).copy())

    # rebind the __class__ closure
    def closure():
        testclass
    osa = testclass.__setattr__
    new_closure = tuple(closure.__closure__[0] if n == '__class__' else c
                        for n, c in zip(osa.__code__.co_freevars, osa.__closure__))
    testclass.__setattr__ = type(osa)(
        osa.__code__, osa.__globals__, osa.__name__,
        osa.__defaults__, new_closure)

    return testclass
```

This function jumps through a few hoops to insert an intermediate class that'll intercept any properly delegated `__setattr__` call. It'll work even if you don't have any base classes other than the default `object` (which wouldn't let us replace `__setattr__` for an easier path to test this).

It does make the assumption that you are using `super().__setattr__()` to delegate, where you used `super()` without arguments. It also assumes there is no meta class involved.

The extra `__setattr__` is injected in a manner consistent with the existing MRO; the extra intermediate class is injected between the original class and the rest of the MRO, and delegates the `__setattr__` call onwards.

To use this in a test, you'd produce a new class with the above function, create an instance then set attributes on that instance:

```
MyTestClass = inject_tester_class(MyClass)
my_test_instance = MyTestClass()
my_test_instance.foo = 'bar'
my_test_instance.assertSetAttrDelegatedFor('foo', 'bar')
```

If setting `foo` is not delegated, an `AssertionError` exception is raised, which the `unittest` test runner records as a test failure.